# Pandas not Working after updating Excel with MS Azure

Tags: microsoft-excel, python

I want to use my Python program for reading/manipulating excel files. All worked fine so far, until I got a new Laptop which is win10 with MS Office 365 including MS Azure Information Protection. Now I can not read Excel sheets from my Python program using Pandas (pandas version 0.20.3) . Is there any possibility to read the excel files again? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error message? What? Did you tried some very basic code to access Excel files? ... Do you have 32 or 64 bit Office? Was that the same also before? ...

Comment: I used office 2016 , but i'm not sure if it was 32 bit or 64 bit before (now its 64 bit).There is no error message, just an empty DataFrame ( not empty in the older version). The Problem is also, that i cannot deactivate the Azure Add-In. The code stayed the same. If I try it with my private pc , there are no issues. So maybe this Azure does not grant acces to the file (accessing with Spyder)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a link that may be help here..
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob